# How can I subscribe to a Channel from an internal proccess? (trying to keep a persistent connection)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a chat room, when a user has a connected socket, we broadcast to that. But when the user is not connected, I want to log information about what the user missed(messages, etc.)

My initial thought it to have an GenServer that accepts and stores the data until the user comes back online.

How can I have an internal process subscribe to a Channel?

Something like this `App.RoomChannel.join("rooms:1", _, self())` (this wont work, as the last params needs to be a Socket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to track some meta data about the user information like (the device or the time that user is online, some message notification ... ), you can use Phoenix.Presence to track that information.

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Presence.html

If you want to subscribe to a channel topic.You can use:

```
YourApp.Endpoint.subscribe("channel_topic")
```

Follow instruction from `Phoenix.Channel` [Subscribing to external topics](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html)

Comment: ```App.Endpoint.subscribe``` was what I was looking for. Thanks!